# Distinguished open subset of intersection of two affine open subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $X$ is a scheme, $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B$ are two affine open subsets such that their intersection, say $U$, is not empty.

Then let $f$ be an element in $A$ such that $D(f)$ is contained in $U$, then we know $D(f)$ equal $\operatorname{Spec} A_f$. Now since $D(f)$ is also an open affine subset of $\operatorname{Spec} B$, can I find some $g$ in $B$ such that $D(f)$ equal $D(g)$ and $A_f$ isomorphic to $B_g$?

If this is not sure, does a weaker statement that there exist some open cover of $U$ by distinguished open subset $D(f_i)$ such that there are $g_i$ in $B$ and $D(f_i)$ = $D(g_i)$ hold?

Comment: Please, please, please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$ instead of leaving it outside math mode.

Comment: Please also make use of the search feature - pasting the first few words of your title in to the search bar returns the duplicate as the second result after your question (and thus likely the first result before you had asked).

Comment: Sorry!!! I am not so familiar with Latex and this site, I will try to avoid these in the future.